# Netbeans 10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++, macos, netbeans, linker

I am a newcomer to C++. I am losing my mind over this issue (I have checked and tried other solutions from people having this very issue on Stack Overflow, yet for some reason I am unable to resolve it). I have the following files -

**stdafx.h**

```
#ifndef STDAFX_H
#define STDAFX_

#endif /* STDAFX_H */

#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
```

**geometry.h**

```
#ifndef GEOMETRY_H
#define GEOMETRY_H



#endif /* GEOMETRY_H */

#pragma once

double PI = 3.1415;

class Circle    {
public:
    double radius;
    double area() const;
    double circumference() const;
};
```

**geometry.cpp**

```
#include "geometry.h"

double Circle::area() const {
    return PI*radius*radius;
}

double Circle::circumference() const {
    return 2*PI*radius;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "geometry.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    Circle c;
    c.radius = 2.0;
    cout << c.area();
    cout << c.circumference();
}
```

The error I am getting is -

```
> cd '/Users/arpanganguli/NetBeansProjects/Chapter8'
/usr/bin/make -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile- 
Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
"/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile- 
Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/chapter8
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/chapter8 build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/geometry.o 
build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o 
duplicate symbol _PI in:
build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/geometry.o
build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/chapter8] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong? I am using Netbeans 10 on MacOS (if this information is helpful). I believe what the error is trying to tell me is that I am linking the same files twice, but if I don't like main.cpp and geometry.cpp through geometry.h, I will not be able to call the function in main.cpp. Can someone please help?

Comment: Move `double PI = 3.1415;` to "geometry.cpp" or make it a member of the `Circle` class.

Comment: Ah brilliant! Thanks! That worked! I have a follow-up question - why is it wrong to put PI in the geometry.h file? And say, if I have to create another .h and .cpp file that uses PI, would I need to still define PI in the cpp file? I thought defining it in geometry.h file and making it public was enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't define a variable more than once. You include the header file in both geometry.cpp and main.cpp which causes it to be defined twice. As I mentioned in the comments, you can move the definition to the "geometry.cpp" file. If you want to use it in some other file, declare it in geometry.h as `extern double PI;` and still define it in geometry.cpp.

geometry.h

```
#pragma once

// Tell the compiler "this var exists, but in another file"
extern double PI;

class Circle    {
public:
    double radius;
    double area() const;
    double circumference() const;
};
```

geometry.cpp

```
#include "geometry.h"

// It is defined here
double PI = 3.1415;

double Circle::area() const {
    return PI*radius*radius;
}

double Circle::circumference() const {
    return 2*PI*radius;
}
```

Assuming the value of Pi never changes, you could also make it a const variable. Then you can go back to defining it in "geometry.h"

```
const double PI = 3.1415;
```

Or, to avoid a global variable altogether, make it a member of the `Circle` class:

```
class Circle    {
public:
    const double PI = 3.1415;
    double radius;
    double area() const;
    double circumference() const;
};
```

There's more to it than I can cover here. There are plenty of good C++ books listed here: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/669576)